# Error PrestaShop “Cannot select any valid SQL engine. at line 302 in file classes/db/Db.php”

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop

Good Morning,

I had a problem with the files on the server where they were all deleted, however I had a backup of the entire site, since this was done a data reset, which took place normally, but what happens now is the following:

```
Cannot select any valid SQL engine.
at line 302 in file classes/db/Db.php

297.         } elseif (extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
298.             $class = 'DbMySQLi';
299.         }
300. 
301.         if (empty($class)) {
302.             throw new PrestaShopException('Cannot select any valid SQL engine.');
303.         }
304. 
305.         return $class;
306.     }
307. 
DbCore::getClass - [line 236 - classes/db/Db.php]
DbCore::getInstance - [line 48 - config/alias.php]
pSQL - [line 340 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```

I've done everything, checked and activated the extensions and nothing.

Will I have to ask my host to reset and then restore?

Is that even trying to install a new store PrestaShop gives this error.

Thank you.

Comment: `Will I have to ask my host to reset and then restore?` Try it ;)

Comment: did you find any solution?!